# Django + GUnicorn ASGI with SCRIPT_NAME

Tags: django, docker, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, asgi

I have a Django application running with a gunicorn ASGI server and an NGINX reverse proxy for serving static content. All are packaged within a docker container.
Now I want to serve this container behind a reverse proxy with a path prefix, e.g. "mydomain.com/djangoapp/". The problem is, that Django doesn't know it's hosted under a subpath, and for example, the Django admin application then always redirects to the root path "/" instead of "/djangoapp/".

I already read that there are several settings that handle this problem.

1. I tried setting the "FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME" in the Django settings directly to "/djangoapp". It worked for the admin login page, but after clicking the login button it redirected to the wrong root "/".
2. I tried setting the "SCRIPT_NAME" environment variable of the gunicorn server to "/djangoapp". It did not apply at all.

I'm running now out of ideas on what else to try. Does anybody else have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` should work.  For the post-login redirect you need to properly set [`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)